# Por qué sentencia update MySQL no funciona?

Tags: mysql, update

en una bdd de MySQL tiempo atrás hice un trigger para automatizar unos update, hoy he caído en cuenta que el campo al que hago el update no ha tenido cambios últimamente, ejecuté manualmente el UPDATE, sin embargo no funciona:

```
UPDATE `orders` SET `pay_day` = '2023-01-15 00:00:00' WHERE `id` = 2172;
```

> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0.134s
> [image: En phpmyadmin tampoco se ejecuta]

La Orden si existe:

[image: La orden existe]

El tipo de dato de este campo es DATE:

[image: Tipo de dato del campo]

También he hecho el Update sin hora, solo fecha y tampoco funciona:

[image: update sin hora]

Comment: porque la sentencia where manda y eso quiere decir que no hay un id 2172, tambien sucede eso cuando la tabla tiene un trigeer que no se cumple al generar el update

Comment: Haz un `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = '2172'` y verifica que el registro exista. ;)

Comment: Si existe la orden, eso es lo extraño

Comment: chekea el trigeer verifica si funciona, si no funciona el trigeer se hace automaticamente un rollback

Comment: Estás seguro que el campo `pay_day` tiene un valor diferente al que estás enviando en el update? Si es el mismo, por eso devuelve `0 rows affected.`

Comment: @javdromero el tipo de dato es DATE, este update lo vengo usando desde hace bastante tiempo y siempre actualizaba es por eso que lo qutomatice con un trigger, y todo funcionaba normalmente, hasta hoy que me percate que muchos registros no tenian información correctam por eso quise arreglar manualmente y es ahí que me percato que los update a este campo no funcionan

Comment: Eso no fue lo que pregunté. Indiqué que revises el valor (valor, no tipo de dato) como tal de la columna pay_day de ese registro. Si envias a hacer un update con un valor que ya tiene, mysql no lo hace ya que no tiene sentido hacer update con el mismo valor.

Comment: @javdromero actualmente el campo pay_day tiene el valor '2023-03-10', no está vacío ni tiene el valor que deseo poner que es '2023-01-15'

Comment: Puedes probar haciendo update a otro campo de la misma tabla pero del mismo registro. Funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que el nombre de la tabla y las columnas son correctos, revisa que la fecha tiempo sea un valor correcto para esa columna (tal vez la columna no es datetime), y que el registro con el id 2172 exista.

Si el valor es incorrecto simplemente tienes que cambiarlo. También puedes considerar cambiar el tipo de dato a solo date ya que no veo que sea necesario que tengas la hora.

Si el id es de un registro que no existe tendrás que ver porque llegó a ese id.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/).